# Visual Studio Code - Change the value of a specific integer with a math operation in a line across multiple pages

Tags: visual-studio-code, replace, find

Not sure if this is something that can be done through Visual Studio Code, but I thought I would check here before I go ahead and manually modify thousands of lines in my project.

Please see the example below to help explain the issue I'm facing.

I have multiple files spread across multiple folders with an identifying text (in this case, Bolts), with another identifier (in this case, quality) value which equals an integer that is different on each page. I would like to know if it's possible to replace these integers with the updated integers through a basic mathematical equation.

Page A:

```
{
   "key": "storage01/bolts",
   "quality": 53.12,
   "weight": 30
},
{
   "key": "storage01/cogs",
   "quality": 39.17,
   "weight": 29
}
```

Page B:

```
{
   "key": "storage02/bolts",
   "quality": 18.9,
   "weight": 30
},
{
   "key": "storage02/cogs",
   "quality": 76.2,
   "weight": 29
}
```

I would like to change both numbers of the quality by multiplying them by 0.29 so the results would end up like this ..

Page A:

```
{
   "key": "storage01/bolts",
   "quality": 15.4048,
   "weight": 30
},
{
   "key": "storage01/cogs",
   "quality": 39.17,
   "weight": 29
}
```

Page B:

```
{
   "key": "storage02/bolts",
   "quality": 5.481,
   "weight": 30
},
{
   "key": "storage02/cogs",
   "quality": 76.2,
   "weight": 29
}
```

Comment: write a simple python script to parse and adjust the files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the help of [map-replace.js](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Yukai.map-replace-js) and one other extension [Search Editor: Apply Changes](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jakearl.search-editor-apply-changes) you can do this pretty easily.  Thanks to @rioV8 for the first extension, its replacement code and the second regex.

The idea is to do a search across files in a Search Editor, map-replace those values in that editor and then save those changes to all the underlying files.

(1)  Open a new Search Editor (from command palette or make a keybinding to the command) or do a Search in the Panel and then choose `Open in Editor`.

(2)  Do a regex search for `\{\s*.*bolts[\w\W]*?\}`

(3)  Now in the Search Editor tab do a Find with `(?<="quality":\s*)[\d.]+`

(3)  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to select all the matches (you may have to click in the editor first).

(4)  Run `Map and Replace Selection with JavaScript Function` with `` (v, i) => `${(Number(v)*0.29).toFixed(2)} `` to make the desired changes.  Set `toFixed()` to what you want.

(5)  Run `Apply Search Editor changes to worksapce` from `Search Editor: Apply Changes` extension

and your changes will be saved within all the files.  Pretty neat to use these extensions and the Search Editor functionality together - yours is a good use case (as long as the initial regex across files isn't super difficult to get right).

(6)  `Save all`

---

---

Demo (with simplified replace since I can't seem to paste into the input box):

[image: map-replace with apply all changes demo]

Comment: Sadly not. Regardless, I'll look into maybe creating a Python to parse the .json files thought, and attempt to get it to work there. Your effort and help on this matter has been greatly appreciated. Much obliged.

Comment: I simplified it quite a bit, eliminating the need for a lookbehind which was the trickiest part of the solution.  We will get this to work ;>}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216759/discussion-between-khaled-and-mark).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the extension [map-replace-js](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Yukai.map-replace-js)

You select the numbers with a regex  `(?<="quality": )[\d.]+`

Use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to select all occurrences in the file.

Then call the `Map and Replace Selection with JavaScript Function` command and use the following expression to convert the numbers

```
(v, i) => `${(Number(v)*0.29).toFixed(2)}`
```

You have to do this in every file

Comment: Okay. This is awesome. It has sped up the work quite a bit. The problem is when I'm searching through the files, I need to search by "Bolts" as there are other items in the inventory which also has the Quality tag. Is there a way to help with the searching for this, or do I still have to do it manually to open each file that has Bolts, then select the Quantity number, and then run '(v, i) => `${(Number(v)*0.29).toFixed(2)}`' - Regardless, I thank you for this. it has made the job slightly less tedious

Comment: if you have a lot of files a script is the most elegant solution, using command line arguments you can change the criteria (like "bolts"). You can search globally for bolts, select all occasions then select the number on the next line (with multiple cursors) and the apply the map